# How can I remove existing control in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, controls

My target is delete actual control on the map to create it again with updated data.

I know about control.remove() but to use this function I need first get control object.

That's my control legend basic from L.control:

[Leaflet control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qw9n.png)

And here is the code to create L.control:

```
function legend(map)
{
    var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});
    
    legend.onAdd = function (map) {

        var elements = [];
        
        map.eachLayer(function(layer){
        if (layer._icon)
        {
            elements.push("svg");
        }
        });
        

            var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
                elements,
                labels = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                    div.innerHTML +=
                        '<i>'elements[i]'</i><br>';
                        
                }

            return div;
        };

    legend.addTo(map);
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function legend(map) {
  var legend = L.control({ position: 'bottomright' });

  legend.onAdd = function (map) {

    var elements = [];

    map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
      if (layer._icon) {
        elements.push("svg");
      }
    });


    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
      elements,
      labels = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      div.innerHTML +=
        '<i style="' elements[i] '"></i><br>';

    }

    return div;
  };

  legend.addTo(map);
  return legend
}

const legendInstance = legend(map);
// remove 
legendInstance.remove()
```

you must return and save control instance if you want remove

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).